# Show that $[B:A]=[f(B):f(A)]\,[(B\cap K):(A\cap K)]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G, H$ finte groups and $f:G\to H$ a homomorphism wirh Kernel $K$. Let $A<B$ subgroups of $G$ and $f(A)<f(B)$ the images. Show that $$[B:A]=[f(B):f(A)]\,[(B\cap K):(A\cap K)]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From First Isomorphism Theorem:

$\frac{|B|}{|ker(f_{|_B})|}=|f(B)|$

And

$\frac{|A|}{|ker(f_{|_A})|}=|f(A)|$

$\implies \frac{|B|}{|A|} = \frac{|f(B)|}{|f(A)|}\frac{ker(f_{|_B})}{ker(f_{|_A})} $

And, $ker(f_{|_B}) = B \cap K$ and $ker(f_{|_A}) = A \cap K$

$\implies [B:A] = [f(B):f(A)][(B\cap K):(A \cap K)]$